# JSON with data from Database in Android

Tags: android, json

I am trying to retrieve all the database and create a and individual JSON for each row eg:

```
{ "id":"1", "name":"John"}
{ "id":"2", "name":"Mick"}
{ "id":"3", "name":"Tom"}
```

This is my select code in my DBQuery.java file to fetch the users:

```
public ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> getUser(){

    ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>userArrayList = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();

    String selectQuery = "SELECT * FROM user ORDER BY name";

    SQLiteDatabase database = this.getWritableDatabase();

    Cursor cursor = database.rawQuery(selectQuery, null);

    if(cursor.moveToFirst()){

        do{

            HashMap<String, String> contactMap = new HashMap<String, String>();

            contactMap.put("d", cursor.getString(0));
            contactMap.put("name", cursor.getString(1));

            userArrayList.add(contactMap);

        } while(cursor.moveToNext());

    }

    return userArrayList;

}
```

And this is my code so far for the JSON object:

```
public class user {
private String id;
private String name;

public user (String id, String name) {
    this.name = id;
    this.gender = name;
}

public String toJson() {
    Gson gson = new Gson();
    String json = gson.toJson(this);
    return json;
}

public static user constructFromJson(String json) {
    Gson gson = new Gson();
    return gson.fromJson(json, user.class);
}

}
```

I am now completely lost and don't know how to finish it.

Answer (score 3):

I highly suggest you to use org.json.JSONObject, it is simple and reliable.
Try with:

```
    JSONArray jArray = new JSONArray();

    while (cursor.moveToNext()) {

        JSONObject jObject = new JSONObject();
        jObject.put("id",cursor.getString(0));
        jObject.put("name",cursor.getString(1));

        jArray.put(jObject);

    }
```

You will have all of your json db entries in the json array.